# Is compatibilism still considered a valid approach to free will?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, quantum-physics, free-will

Has the Free Will Theorem of Conway and Kochen been taken seriously by the philosophical community? Is compatibilism still considered a valid approach to free will?

Comment: welcome! Do you think you could provide a little more context here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That theorem ([overview](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~jas/one/freewill-theorem.html)) is often taken out of context. His suggestive naming of the behavior or elementary particles as "free will" irked a lot of people, especially as the connection to what we consider free will is phenomenally vague. It's almost akin to noting that Heisenberg Uncertainty suggests a lack of determinism (for the more quantum-mechanically literate, look into Bell's Theorem).

So the theorem is taken very seriously, but not necessarily having anything to do with what we consider free will.

Answer (score 10):

Mixedmath's answer is a good one. I'd also like to add this supplementary data from a physicist point of view. As Sheldon Goldstein said: "We point out that for stochastic models this conclusion is not correct, while for deterministic models it is not new."

http://math.rutgers.edu/~oldstein/papers/fwtGTTZ.pdf

Besides, even if you stick to the non-compatiblist world view there are other points to be made for freewill than just indeterminism. I've written a [bastardised argument](http://sinasalek.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/quantum-physics-doesnt-add-much-to-the-problem-of-freewill/) in my blog for a general target audience.

Comment: Can you link directly to the argument in your blog?  I don't think people on here are going to go to the effort to look for it.

Comment: @Muhd I took the liberty to find Sina's argument and adjust the link