# Standard Argument against free will rebuttal

Tags: free-will, determinism

The Standard argument against free will states that an action is either predetermined or random and that these two options exhaust all the possibilities, leaving no room for true free will.

To those that believe that this dilemma is fallacious, could point me to some sources of what past philosophers have said in rebutting this issue, thanks.

Comment: We already had a question on this [Is free will a third option aside from chance and necessity?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/18424/9148) [Information Philosopher](http://www.informationphilosopher.com/freedom/standard_argument.html) gives an extensive breakdown of the flaws of the standard argument.

Comment: I meant specifically asking for sources. I've edited the question.